# Azure - LogicApps injecting a Log Analytics doesn't inject logs

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm intending to inject logs from Logic Apps to Log Analytics workspace. (Aim : Poll data from remote REST API and push them in Sentinel). I follow [Microsoft Standard procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/create-custom-connector#connect-with-logic-apps) as follows, keeping every resource in same region, same RG:

- Create Data Collection Endpoint `DCEMyTable`,
- Create Log Analytics Workspace `LogAnalyticstodelete`,
- Create new Data Collection Rule `DCRMyTable` bound to `DCEMyTable`,
- Add new table in Log Analytics Workspace `MyTable_CL` bound to `DCRMyTable` and `DCEMyTable`, adding a very simple JSON:

```json
{
 "Time": "2023-11-06T07:34:00Z",
 "Value": "passed"
}
```

- Transform it w/ KQL: `source| project-rename TimeGenerated = Time` and validate
- Create an Action in Logic Apps : "Log Analytics Data Collector API" as follows:
  [image: Logic Apps]

I used Workspace ID & Key found in Linux Agents of my LogAnalytics Workspace to connect, maybe it's the buggy move.

When fired, Logic Apps yields a HTTP 200 code, but no log seems inserted in Log Analytics. Did some of you tried this usecase successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used Workspace ID & Key found in Linux Agents of my Log Analytics Workspace to connect, maybe it's the buggy move.

If you have a Consumption Logic app, then you can use both Windows and Linux Agent Workspace ID and Workspace Key to create a connection to log analytics workspace. But If you have a Standard Logic app then you need to use only Windows Agent Workspace ID and Workspace Key.

I am able to send the logs from a Consumption Logic app to log analytics workspace as shown below.

[image]

***Logs in log analytics workspace***-

[image]

Please try to wait for sometime if you are not able to see the logs instantly after logic app execution and refresh the page if needed. I believe you will also be able to get the logs alike me.